# Converting ObservableCollection<T> to ObservableCollection<String>

Tags: c#, collections, generic-collections

I have an `ObservableCollection<T>`.  T has a ToString() method.  What I'd like to do is convert the `ObservableCollection<T>` to `ObservableCollection<string>`.  Having done a quick search, I found a few articles that suggested a foreach approach - is there another way?  e.g.:

```
myCollection.ToObservableCollection();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var newCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(myCollection.Select(x => x.ToString()));
```